# remove some string between strings

Tags: c#

I have some strings, like

```
string word = "This is example text/WS95    1300 G934 100 DAB"
```

I want to remove the string between WS95 and G934 so  the result will be :
"This is example text/WS95 G934 100 DAB"

is there any way to do it? I try with indexof

```
int start = word.IndexOf("WS95") + "WS95".length;
int end = word.LastIndexOf("G");
```

after that, I'm stuck.

Maybe someone has any idea after this?

> Expected result: "This is example text/WS95 G934 100 DAB"

Thankyou

Comment: You might want to look at the two argument form of string's [`.Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Remove_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: public string Remove(int StartIndex, int count) , hmm what should i put to the count parameter? hmm end - start?

Comment: What happens when the string has repeated words? For eg., G934 word in the string ' This is example text/WS95 G934 100 DAB and G934 120 DAB.' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
string word = "This is example text/WS95    1300 G934 100 DAB";
var result = Regex.Replace(word, @"(?<=WS95).*(?= G934)","");
```

[Live Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SrRyln)

Or

```
string word = "This is example text/WS95    1300 G934 100 DAB";
var match = Regex.Matches(word, @"(.*WS95)(.*1300)(.*)")[0];
var result = match.Groups[1].Value+match.Groups[3].Value;
```

[Live Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pmBzKA)

Answer (score 1):

```
var key1 = "WS95";
var key2 = "G934";
string word = "This is example text/WS95    1300 G934 100 DAB";
var resultStrings = word.Split(new[] { key1 }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var resultStrings2 = resultStrings[1].Split(new[] { key2 }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var result = resultStrings[0] + key1 +" "+ key2 + resultStrings2[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

According to given string.

```
string name = "This is example text/WS95    1300 G934 100 DAB";

    Console.WriteLine("The entire string is '{0}'", name);

    // remove the contents, identified by finding the `WS95` and `G934` in the string...
    int foundS1 = name.IndexOf("WS95");
    int foundS2 = name.IndexOf("G934", foundS1 + 1);
    if (foundS1 != foundS2 && foundS1 >= 0) {

        name = name.Remove(foundS1 + 4, (foundS2-5) - foundS1);

        Console.WriteLine("After removing '{0}'", name);
    }
```

Fiddle Link: [C# Fiddle Link.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6qLCBt)

Answer (score 0):

If your words are always delimited by spaces, and you want/don't mind removing extra spaces here's one way:

```
string word = "This is example text/WS95    1300 G934 100 DAB";
string[] array = word.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int index1 = Array.IndexOf(array, "text/WS95"); // has to be a whole word between spaces
int index2 = Array.IndexOf(array,"G934");
var result = String.Join(" ",array.Take(index1 + 1).Concat(array.Skip(index2)));
```